# cannot concatenate 'str' and 'WSGIRequest' objects

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I keep getting this error when I try to load my templates:

`TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'WSGIRequest' objects`

Here is a link to the paste: https://gist.github.com/3b7039baf13d91a67de2

You will notice that one of the lines from the traceback points to my views.py and the last line in the method below. Could this last line be the problem and if so how can I go about fixing it. Thanks in advance

```
def all(request):
    """This returns all the photos in the database
    """
    return render_to_response(request, 'photos/all.html', {'photos':
        Photo.objects.all().order_by('-date_added')})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

render_to_response doesn't accept request as its first argument.

render, from Django 1.3, however does. Perhaps that the method you intended to use?